# Получить из xml более точные данные

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, beautiful-soup, bs4

Есть тег `xml`:

```xml
<authors>
<author lang="EN" num="1">
<lastname>Emel'yanov</lastname>
<initials>I G</initials>
<authorid>17028</authorid>
<spin>2308-0271</spin>
<email>oldim96@mail.ru</email>
<affiliations>
<affiliation lang="EN" num="1">
<orgname>Ural Federal University</orgname>
<address>Ekaterinburg, Russia</address>
</affiliation>
<affiliation lang="EN" num="2">
<orgname>Institute of Engineering Science, Ural Branch of the Russian Academy of Sciences</orgname>
<address>Ekaterinburg, Russia</address>
</affiliation>
</affiliations>
</author>
-<author lang="EN" num="2">
<lastname>Mironov</lastname>
<initials>V I</initials>
-<affiliations>
-<affiliation lang="EN" num="1">
<orgname>Ural Federal University</orgname>
<address>Ekaterinburg, Russia</address>
</affiliation>
-<affiliation lang="EN" num="2">
<orgname>Institute of Engineering Science, Ural Branch of the Russian Academy of Sciences</orgname>
<address>Ekaterinburg, Russia</address>
</affiliation>
</affiliations>
</author>
-<author lang="EN" num="3">
<lastname>Lukashuk</lastname>
<initials>O A</initials>
<authorid>607446</authorid>
<spin>9967-3730</spin>
-<affiliations>
-<affiliation lang="EN" num="1">
<orgname>Ural Federal University</orgname>
<address>Ekaterinburg, Russia</address>
</affiliation>
</affiliations>
</author>
</authors>
```

Мне из него нужно получить ФИО авторов и все организации, привязанные к авторам.

Делаю так:

```
def get_author_full_name(author_node) -> str:
    return str(author_node.lastname) + ' ' + str(author_node.initials) + ' ' + str(author_node.orgname)


def get_authors(item) -> list:
    authors = item.select('authors > author')

    num_author_by_authors = dict()

    for author in authors:
        num = author['num']
        if num not in num_author_by_authors:
            num_author_by_authors[num] = []

        num_author_by_authors[num].append(author)

    authors_full_name = []

    for num, authors in num_author_by_authors.items():
        if len(authors) == 1:
            full_name = get_author_full_name(authors[0])
            authors_full_name.append(full_name)

        else:
            full_name = get_author_full_name(authors[0])

            for author in authors:
                if author['lang'] == "RU":
                    full_name = get_author_full_name(author)
                    break

            authors_full_name.append(full_name)

    return authors_full_name
```

Но выходит, что только первая организация получается "привязанной". Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поправить код для того, чтобы обе организации у каждого автора были видны.

Желаемый результат:

```
["<lastname>Emel'yanov</lastname> <initials>I G</initials> <orgname>Ural Federal University</orgname> <orgname>Institute of Engineering Science, Ural Branch of the Russian Academy of Sciences</orgname>", '<lastname>Mironov</lastname> <initials>V I</initials> <orgname>Ural Federal University</orgname> <orgname>Institute of Engineering Science, Ural Branch of the Russian Academy of Sciences</orgname>', '<lastname>Lukashuk</lastname> <initials>O A</initials> <orgname>Ural Federal University</orgname>']
```

Comment: Используете `bs4`?

Comment: @gil9red, да, bs4

Comment: @gil9red, Вы правы. Убрала из второй функции. Сейчас поправлю в вопросе. Как же всё-таки добавить обе организации?

Comment: Еще вопрос, атрибут `num` это уникальный идентификатор автора? Нужно вернуть именно список строк? У вас список это результат get_author_full_name

Comment: @gil9red, num - номер автора в этом огромном теге. Да, нужно именно список строк

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз точкой заполнения является одна функция, то в ней и нужно сделать доработку:

```
def get_author_full_name(author_node) -> str:
    text = '{} {}'.format(author_node.lastname, author_node.initials)

    for orgname in author_node.select('affiliations > affiliation > orgname'):
        text += ' {}'.format(orgname)

    return text
```

Результат парсинга (построчно):

```
<lastname>Emel'yanov</lastname> <initials>I G</initials> <orgname>Ural Federal University</orgname> <orgname>Ural Federal University</orgname> <orgname>Institute of Engineering Science, Ural Branch of the Russian Academy of Sciences</orgname>
<lastname>Mironov</lastname> <initials>V I</initials> <orgname>Ural Federal University</orgname> <orgname>Ural Federal University</orgname> <orgname>Institute of Engineering Science, Ural Branch of the Russian Academy of Sciences</orgname>
<lastname>Lukashuk</lastname> <initials>O A</initials> <orgname>Ural Federal University</orgname> <orgname>Ural Federal University</orgname>
```

---

Весь код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_author_full_name(author_node) -> str:
    text = '{} {}'.format(author_node.lastname, author_node.initials)

    for orgname in author_node.select('affiliations > affiliation > orgname'):
        text += ' {}'.format(orgname)

    return text


def get_authors(item) -> list:
    num_author_by_authors = dict()

    for author in item.select('authors > author'):
        num = author['num']
        if num not in num_author_by_authors:
            num_author_by_authors[num] = []

        num_author_by_authors[num].append(author)

    authors_full_name = []

    for num, authors in num_author_by_authors.items():
        if len(authors) == 1:
            full_name = get_author_full_name(authors[0])
            authors_full_name.append(full_name)

        else:
            full_name = get_author_full_name(authors[0])

            for author in authors:
                if author['lang'] == "RU":
                    full_name = get_author_full_name(author)
                    break

            authors_full_name.append(full_name)

    return authors_full_name

xml = """
<authors>
    <author lang="EN" num="1">
        <lastname>Emel'yanov</lastname>
        <initials>I G</initials>
        <authorid>17028</authorid>
        <spin>2308-0271</spin>
        <email>oldim96@mail.ru</email>
        <affiliations>
            <affiliation lang="EN" num="1">
                <orgname>Ural Federal University</orgname>
                <address>Ekaterinburg, Russia</address>
            </affiliation>
            <affiliation lang="EN" num="2">
                <orgname>Institute of Engineering Science, Ural Branch of the Russian Academy of Sciences</orgname>
                <address>Ekaterinburg, Russia</address>
            </affiliation>
        </affiliations>
    </author>
    <author lang="EN" num="2">
        <lastname>Mironov</lastname>
        <initials>V I</initials>
        <affiliations>
            <affiliation lang="EN" num="1">
                <orgname>Ural Federal University</orgname>
                <address>Ekaterinburg, Russia</address>
            </affiliation>-<affiliation lang="EN" num="2">
                <orgname>Institute of Engineering Science, Ural Branch of the Russian Academy of Sciences</orgname>
                <address>Ekaterinburg, Russia</address>
            </affiliation>
        </affiliations>
    </author>
    <author lang="EN" num="3">
        <lastname>Lukashuk</lastname>
        <initials>O A</initials>
        <authorid>607446</authorid>
        <spin>9967-3730</spin>
        <affiliations>
            <affiliation lang="EN" num="1">
                <orgname>Ural Federal University</orgname>
                <address>Ekaterinburg, Russia</address>
            </affiliation>
        </affiliations>
    </author>
</authors>
"""

root = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'lxml')

for author in get_authors(root):
    print(author)
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но у меня задваивается первая организация

Comment: @Ireen1985, моя невнимательность -- убрал третий параметр из строки в get_author_full_name

Comment: идеально! Всё работает! Спасибо!