# Как спарсить только нужные div на Python

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, парсер, python-3.6

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как собрать только нужные данные у блоков, если они не вложены в те, по которым их можно идентифицировать. Проще говоря, [есть сайт](https://www.myscore.ru/baseball/), у него структура построена следующим образом:

```
<div class="sportName baseball">
    <div class="event__header">
        <div class="icon--flag event__title fl_205" title="Венесуэла">
            <div class="event__titleBox">
               <span class="event__title--type">ВЕНЕСУЭЛА</span>
               <span class="event__title--name" title="ЛВБП">ЛВБП</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="g_6_MmpBOXpa" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--scheduled event__match--twoLine"></div>
    <div id="g_6_MmpBOtha" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--scheduled event__match--twoLine"></div>
    <div id="g_6_MmprgOXpa" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--scheduled event__match--twoLine"></div>

    <div class="event__header">
        <div class="icon--flag event__title fl_205" title="Мексика">
            <div class="event__titleBox">
                <span class="event__title--type">МЕКСИКА</span>
                <span class="event__title--name" title="ЛМП">ЛМП</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="g_6_Mmthrpa" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--scheduled event__match--twoLine"></div>
    <div id="g_6_MthrBOtha" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--scheduled event__match--twoLine"></div>
    <div id="g_6_MmprgOjtr" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--scheduled event__match--twoLine"></div>
</div>
```

Можно ли как-то прописать, что если содержимое `div` с `class="event__header"` удовлетворяет условиям, содержит в тегах `<span class="event__title--type">ВЕНЕСУЭЛА</span>` и `<span class="event__title--name" title="ЛВБП">ЛВБП</span>` `ВЕНЕСУЭЛА` и `ЛВБПЭ`, соответственно, то собираем, например, `id` у `div title="Подробности матча!"`, до следующего `div` с `class="event__header"`, или есть другие более правильные варианты?

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

ПРАВКИ:
Как-то не выходит использовать `find_next_siblings`, может кто знает, что не так?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

test_html = """
<div class="sportName baseball">
    <div class="event__header">
        <div class="icon--flag event__title fl_205" title="Венесуэла">
            <div class="event__titleBox">
                <span class="event__title--type">ВЕНЕСУЭЛА</span>
                <span class="event__title--name" title="ЛВБП">ЛВБП</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="g_6_MmpBOXpa" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--scheduled event__match--twoLine"></div>
    <div id="g_6_MmpBOtha" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--scheduled event__match--twoLine"></div>
    <div id="g_6_MmprgOXpa" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--scheduled event__match--twoLine"></div>

    <div class="event__header">
        <div class="icon--flag event__title fl_205" title="Мексика">
            <div class="event__titleBox">
                <span class="event__title--type">МЕКСИКА</span>
                <span class="event__title--name" title="ЛМП">ЛМП</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="g_6_Mmthrpa" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--scheduled event__match--twoLine"></div>
    <div id="g_6_MthrBOtha" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--scheduled event__match--twoLine"></div>
    <div id="g_6_MmprgOjtr" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--scheduled event__match--twoLine"></div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(test_html, 'html.parser')
current = soup.find_all("div", class_="event__header")
liga = []
for i in current:
    span1 = i.find_all("span")
    for j in span1:
        span2 = j.get_text()
        liga.append(span2)
        print(span2)
print(liga)
span3 = ["МЕКСИКА"]
for m in span2:
    if m in span3:
        s = current.find_next_siblings("div")
        print(s)
    else:
        print("Совпадений нет")
```

Comment: Там так и написано `<div id>`? Лучше приложите конкретный кусок html, что нужно парсить + опционально ссылку на источник

Comment: ниже привел кусок кода в скрине, а так ссылка вот https://www.myscore.ru/baseball/. по названию лиги(там причем в двух разных div страна и название самой лиги) нужно чтоб и страна и лига удовлетворяла условиям, по ним нужно собрать у матчей, относящейся к этой лиги id

Comment: Текст должен быть в виде текста, а скриншот это дополнительное и опциональное. То, что ссылку привели это хорошо, но лучше, чтобы оно было в вопросе (это я подправлю у вас в вопросе). Поймите, тут сидят забесплатно и чтобы у пользователей было больше желания помочь, нужно как можно больше дать информации по теме вопроса, а в случаи с кодом, еще свой код показать, т.к. не любят вопросы по типу "сделайте за меня, вот вам задание" :) Вот пример хорошего вопроса по парсингу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1055445/201445

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, исправлю вопрос

Comment: Посмотрите на метод `find_next_sibling`.

Comment: исправил, текст вопроса

Comment: не совсем понимаю как тут использовать `find_next_sibling`, пожалуйста, можно подробнее?

Comment: Как-то не выходит использовать `find_next_siblings`

` `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
test_html = """
<div class="sportName baseball">
    <div class="event__header">
       <div class="icon--flag event__title fl_205" title="Венесуэла">
          <div class="event__titleBox">
             <span class="event__title--type">ВЕНЕСУЭЛА</span>
             <span class="event__title--name" title="ЛВБП">ЛВБП</span>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="g_6_UyjXVFhP" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--twoLine">
       <div class="event__check"></div>
       <div class="event__stage">
          <div class="event__stage--block">Завершен</div>
       </div>
       <div class="event__participant event__participant--home">Ла Гуайра</div>
       <div class="event__participant event__participant--away fontBold">Маргарита</div>
       <div class="event__score event__score--home">5</div>
       <div class="event__score event__score--away">7</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--1">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--1">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--2">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--2">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--3">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--3">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--4">1</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--4">1</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--5">2</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--5">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--6">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--6">1</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--7">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--7">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--8">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--8">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--9">2</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--9">3</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--10">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--10">2</div>
       <div class="event__spacer event__spacer--home"></div>
       <div class="event__spacer event__spacer--away"></div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--11">14</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--11">13</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--12">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--12">2</div>
       <div class="event__check"></div>
       <div class="event__icons">
          <div class="event__icon icon--info"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="g_6_6csaRZ0t" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--twoLine">
       <div class="event__check"></div>
       <div class="event__stage">
          <div class="event__stage--block">Завершен</div>
       </div>
       <div class="event__participant event__participant--home">Лара</div>
       <div class="event__participant event__participant--away fontBold">Каракас</div>
       <div class="event__score event__score--home">4</div>
       <div class="event__score event__score--away">9</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--1">2</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--1">2</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--2">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--2">5</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--3">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--3">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--4">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--4">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--5">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--5">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--6">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--6">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--7">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--7">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--8">1</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--8">0</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--9">1</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--9">2</div>
       <div class="event__spacer event__spacer--home"></div>
       <div class="event__spacer event__spacer--away"></div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--11">8</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--11">15</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--home event__part--12">3</div>
       <div class="event__part event__part--away event__part--12">0</div>
       <div class="event__icons"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="event__header">
       <div class="icon--flag event__title fl_205" title="Мексика">
          <div class="event__titleBox">
             <span class="event__title--type">МЕКСИКА</span>
             <span class="event__title--name" title="ЛМП">ЛМП</span>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="g_6_Mmthrpa" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--twoLine"></div>
    <div id="g_6_MthrBOtha" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--twoLine"></div>
    <div id="g_6_MmprgOjtr" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--twoLine"></div>
</div> """

soup = BeautifulSoup(test_html, 'html.parser')
liga = []

ehlist = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'event__header'})
for eh in ehlist:
tlist = eh.find_all('div', attrs={'title':'Венесуэла'})
if tlist:
    for t in tlist:
        splist = t.find_all('span')
        for sp in splist:
            text = sp.get_text()
            liga.append(text)
        print(liga[0] + ": " + liga[1])
        print(' ' * 21 + 'Оч  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 ДИ  Х Ош')
        print(' ' * 21 + '-' * 38)
        
        slist = eh.find_next_siblings() # выборка тегов с данными о матчах
        x = None
        while x == None:
            slist.remove(slist[-1])
            for s in slist:
                x = s.find('span')               
        slist.remove(slist[-1])
        
        for s in slist:                 # формирование строк данных
            text = s.get_text()
            events = text.split('\n')[5:]
            eup = events[2::2]
            edn = events[3::2]
            if eup[10] != '':
                eup.remove(eup[11])
            if edn[10] != '':
                edn.remove(edn[11])
            
            print('%-20s' % events[0], end='')   # форматирование таблицы
            for u in eup:
                print('%+3s' % u, end = '')
            print('\n%-20s' % events[1], end='')    
            for d in edn:
                print('%+3s' % d, end = '')
            print('\n')
```

К вопросу об использовании find_next_sibligs().

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Подскажите, пожалуйста, а как у такого варианта выводить `id` только у тех элементов, которые находятся под и только до следующего `{'class':'event__header'}`

Comment: @ChikChirik, смотрите доработанный вариант программы.